# How can I print my MongoDB queries from loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I want to print all the queries executed on MongoDB from my loopback 3 application when in debug mode. I tried setting "DEBUG" : "loopback:connector:mongodb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Loopback 2 and I also had to check the MongoDB queries for my APIs. I just used `DEBUG=loopback:connector:mongodb node .` command to start my loopback server with debugging enabled.

There is one more alternative way to do this. You can add a key `debug` and set it `true` in your datasource config file datasource.json files.
If the above two methods don't work for you, Please check the values of `debug` property in `MongoDB` function in `node_modules/loopback-connector-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js` file.

Resources
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Setting-debug-strings.html